# IBM DOORS Exporting Formals as HTML file in

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a IBM DOORS database and inside of it there is an project called "Test" which has a symbol as blue folder. Inside of it there is another folder called "ayberk_dxl" which is a yellow folder. What I want to do is, I need to export all formals in ayberk_dxl folder and its sub directories. I am newbie on writing dxl scripts. I have managed to write a script that should perform this operation but there is some errors and I can't solve them. Can anyone give ideas what is wrong with my script please?

Here is my dxl script:

```
// Define the filePath to save HTML files
string filePath = "C:\\\\Users\\\\t22283srv\\\\Desktop\\\\DOORS_EXPORT"

// Recursive function to process folder and its subfolders
void processFolder(Folder folder) {
    Item item
    for item in folder do {
        if (isModule(item)) {
            string itemPath = fullName(item)
            Module mod = read(itemPath)
            // Check if the "Object Text" attribute exists in the module
            if (null != find(mod, "Object Text")) {
                string modName = name(mod)
                string fileName = filePath "\\\\" modName ".html"
                
                // Export the module to an HTML file
                string options = "-html"
                export(mod, fileName, options, "", "", "", "")
                close(mod)
            }
        }
        if (type(item) == "Folder") {
            // Process subfolders
            string folderPath = fullName(item)
            Folder subFolder = find(folderPath)
            processFolder(subFolder)
        }
    }
}

// Get the main folder
Folder mainFolder = find("/TEST/ayberk_dxl")

// Call the function to process the main folder and its subfolders
processFolder(mainFolder)
```

This gives errors shown below:

```
-E- DXL: <Line:14> incorrect arguments for function (export)
-E- DXL: <Line:20> incorrect context for binary op (=)
-E- DXL: <Line:26> incorrect context for binary op (=)
-I- DXL: All done. Errors reported: 3. Warnings reported: 0.
```

Comment: "blue folders" are projects. "yellow folders" are folders. You can convert one into the other but they have different features. For projects, its `type` is "Project", not "Folder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it won't be so easy. There is no DXL perm for a HTML export. You might want to have a look at tools like perhaps http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=803, using its function `emitView`. Or do you use a library that already contains a function named "export"? If so, look at the definition of that function to determine which are the correct arguments. The DXL manual, which resides at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.1/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf, will assist you in finding the correct parameters for each perm.

Your recursive function is generally correct, though "Object Text" is a standard attribute of every formal module, i.e. instead of "isModule" (a perm that does not exist anyway in DOORS, where did you get this code from?), use `if type (item) == 'Formal'`. And: don't use variable names that have the same name as a perm, instead of `item` use e.g. `it`, instead of `folder` use e.g. `f`, otherwise you will have a hard time understanding the error messages.

all in all, your function can look like this

```
void processFolder(Folder f) {
    Item it
    for it in f do {
        if (type(it) == "Formal") {
            string itemPath = fullName(it)
            Module mod = read(itemPath)
            string modName = name(it)
        // do something with the module...
        print modName "-"
            close(mod)
        }
        if (type(it) == "Folder") {
            // Process subfolders
            Folder subFolder = folder(it)
        processFolder(subFolder)
        }
    }
}

processFolder (folder "/myProject")
```